# How can we split values in a column separated by pipe into multiple rows

Tags: unix

For example:

```
Roll No:      Name      City
100|200|300   Vicky     Hyd
400|500|600   Kalyan    Viz
```

into

```
100 vicky Hyd
200 vicky Hyd
300 vicky Hyd
400 Kalyan Viz
500 Kalyan Viz
600 Kalyan Viz
```

Could you please suggest a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to split the string and then print along with other values:

```
awk 'NR!=1{split($1, arr, "|"); for ( i in arr) print arr[i], $2, $3}' file
```